# I can't use rosdep?

Tags: rosdep, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a beginner of Ubuntu (v12.04) and Fuerte ROS.

I've tried several tutorials in ROS and mostly things were OK.

Now, I'm trying to build some stacks i.e. robotino*. But I cannot use rosdep.

```
rosdeps: command not found
```

Did I install ROS incorrectly or lack of some steps to initialize ROS platform?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45319/i-can%27t-use-rosdep?!/) by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2012-10-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on 2012-10-08**:
I've tried to track the error and see that I'm lack of rosbash. So I run "source ${ROS_ROOT}/tools/rosbash/rosbash" but the error comes "No such file or directory"

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-08**:
Have a look at the [environment setup](http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu#fuerte.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-DebEnvironment.Environment_setup) section and the [overlay](http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays) page. You probably don't have your environment set up correctly.

**Comment by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on 2012-10-08**:
thank you @Lorenz!! I've found that I perhaps was lacked of this command in the installation page of ROS: sudo apt-get install python-rosinstall python-rosdep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The command is not `rosdeps` but `rosdep`. You need to install rosdep with:

```
sudo apt-get install python-rosdep
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4